# Diode connected transistor for voltage biasing

Tags: transistors

I am trying hard to demonstrate that the transistor M1 in figure works always in linear region. Transistor M2 is diode connected and consenquently (I am using the EKV model) it works always in saturation:

Vg2 = Vd2 > (Vg2-Vt)/n           Saturation condition

I know that voltage drop Vds2 is surely bigger than Vt but this doesn't allow me to state that the transistor M1 works always in linear region:

Vd1 < (Vg1-Vt)/n                       Linear region condition

I would really appreciate your help, thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assume vt is same for both.
Vg - Vd1 = vt + delta.
Delta is how much ever to allow bias current to flow.

For m1, linear condition is
Vd1 < vg - vt

=>  Vt < vg - Vd1.
But from above we know vg-vd1 = Vt+ delta

=> Vt < vt + delta ( substitution).
This is true. Hence the m1 is in linear

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Since M2 is in saturation, the voltage at gate of M2 is greater than that at source.
$$V_{G2}>V_{S2}$$
But since both the gates are connected and source of M2 is connected to drain of M1,
$$V_{G1}>V_{D1}$$
Which can be re-written as,
$$V_{DS1}<V_{GS1}$$
So M1 works in saturation.